# Images/CSS won't load on OSCommerce

Tags: html, css, image, layout, web

I am working on this website;
http://netadvokaten.se/

It is a standard OsCommerce page and I have not begun to edit it so it is straight out of the package.
From what I can see the Images won't load, and the layout is way off.

I would suspect it was a corrupt install but the same install works on my local server at home.

Does anyone know how I can begin to solve this problem? Google for an hour didn't help.

Comment: have you checked the image source paths? and would you mind explaining what you mean by layout is off?? maybe link to a screenshot of your working version?

Comment: i just saw your #column-left has no intentions of going left... is that what you mean? i checked the style rules and chrome says nothing about float:left or align: left. also the position is default, meaning relative, maybe you wanted absolute?

Comment: also it seems your css rule for the class of the columns is not included... have you made sure all style-rules are present and include-files have correct paths?

Comment: this is how it looks: http://postimage.org/image/fwugm6kol/

The CSS or whatever it is refuses to load.

Answer (score 2):

Your styles and Javascript files are not loading correctly.

You might have a problem with the route or you forgot to upload them.

Comment: Ok, how do I begin to sort that? 
I know I have uploaded them all, I just dragged everything in the folder into the FTPprogram.

How do I check my routs?

Comment: You can use any browser DOM inspector as the one it comes with Google Chrome or just simple by following the CSS or JS links on the source view.